# Extending base-class properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I extend properties from a base 'class' in knockout.js?

I'm trying to setup knockout-validation in my view models but it doesn't work unless my 'sub-class' has an observable that is also `extended`. See the comments in the code snippet below:

```js
// setup knockout validation
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true
});

// base 'class'
function userAddressModelBase(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName);
}

userAddressModel.prototype = new userAddressModelBase({});
userAddressModel.constructor = userAddressModel;

// 'sub-class'
function userAddressModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    userAddressModelBase.call(self, data);
    
    // extend 'base-class' properties; this doesn't work unless the current 'sub-class' also has an observable who is also extended...
    self.firstName.extend({ required: true });
    self.lastName.extend({ required: true });
    
    // the above statement only starts working if I extend an observable from this `sub-class`
    self.city = ko.observable();//.extend({ required: true });
    
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
    
    self.validate = function() {
        
        console.log(self.errors().length);
        if (self.errors().length > 0) {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
            return;
        }
    };
}

var model = new userAddressModel({ firstName: "Ted" });

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```css
.validationMessage{
    color: #ea033d;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /></label><br>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /></label><br>
    <label>City: <input type="text" data-bind="value: city" /></label><br>
    <button data-bind="click: validate">Validate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way to perform inheritance is to use `ko.utils.extend(self, new userAddressModelBase(data));`

```
function userAddressModelBase(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName);
}
```

Below I am using extend to add required validation to firstName and lastName.

```
function userAddressModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.utils.extend(self, new userAddressModelBase(data))
    self.firstName.extend({ required: true });
    self.lastName.extend({ required: true });
};
```

Now in the example if you remove the firstName and then exit the text box you can see that the required message appears.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4vLqkx2/1/

Comment: I don't think my inheritance setup is the issue, however I tried it your way and it still does not extend the base property to knockout-validation's liking.

Comment: I've updated my answer above to be clearer. Are you sure my example is not working. The extend in my example is working when I tried it in Chrome and Safari. You need to exit the field for it to fire.